# Help with the meaning of 読ませたい？

Tags: grammar

The first episode of ボボボーボ・ボーボボ is titled:

> 「毛魂」と書いて「スパークリング」と読ませたい…

Which seems to say "It's written as [hair soul], I want you to read it as [sparkling]"

To my understanding, 読ませたい is a combination of 読ませる＋たい which would equal "to want to make someone read". Is this a correct interpretation?

If so, is this grammar used frequently over 〜て＋ほしい？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to translate it as "I want to have it read as sparkling".  But that leaves a pesky passive voice in there that's not in the original.

On the other hand, a more literal translation seems to be "I want to have others read it as sparkling".  Then we've got the causative without resorting to the passive (though I think the passive construction sounds more natural in English).

It's a bit more challenging to explain why it's not 読んでほしい.  But スパークリング」と読んでほしい just means "I want them to read it as sparkling".  The meaning is similar, but not the same.  It's not merely that "I" **want them** to read it; "I" *want* to **make them** read it a certain way.  Well, *make* is perhaps a bit strong, which is why above I translated it as "to have others read".  But here I'm trying to clarify the difference between the two.

Another construction to consider is よませてほしい.  But that would mean "I want someone to have them read..."

When we say **verb**てほしい we're expressing the idea of wanting someone to do something (for us).  But in this sentence, it's よませたい.  "I" is the one "wanting to cause".

What seems to me the next obvious question is why not have said something like よませられ＋たい.  Here I'm going more out on a limb.  I'd say there are two reasons this could not work: (1) this would make the kanji the subject and as kanji are not sentient (at least as best as I can tell--this is my attempt at humor), they cannot *want* something; (2) even if it were possible for kanji to want something, then the sentence would incorrectly say mean "the kanji want to be made to read".  That's clearly not at all what is intended.  (And here's an interesting question, at least to me: in English we can have a passive causative of a passive-->"it wants to be made to be read as...".  Can this be done in Japanese?)

A final note for which it would be good to hear from a native speaker:  In English we can say things like "I want to be found" or "I want to be crowned the king" etc:  in other words, we can want something be *done* to us (ie we can want a passive action performed).  But, I've never seen such a construct in Japanese.  Can you say something like 見つけられたい?  I don't think so.  In such a case, you would instead say something like 見つけてくれたい perhaps (but I've never seen/heard this either) or just simply 見つけてほしい.  The point being, I don't think you can add たい to a passive verb in Japanese.

So, this circles back to my original inclination to translate the sentence in question as "I want to have it read as sparkling".  The English works and I don't think there's a corresponding literal Japanese version of this.  As with "I want to be found", a different verbal construction would be used in Japanese.